# priority inversion in mutex vs semaphore

Tags: multithreading, mutex, semaphore, thread-priority

Why (and how) mutex can deal with priority inversion and semaphores not?

I read in lots of places that the difference (one of them) between mutex and semaphore is priority inversion, can anyone explain please?

Comment: binary semaphore for that matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29#Semaphores_vs._mutexes):

> Since the mutex knows its current owner, it is possible to promote the priority of the owner whenever a higher-priority task starts waiting on the mutex.